# Redirect Filesystem

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems

Ok, so I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't seem to phrase the problem correctly to get any kind of answer.

What I'm trying to do is launch an application via c# and then have all of it's calls to `SHGetFolderPath` or `Environment.GetFolder`(int .net) return back alternate paths that I specify.

I tried already setting `USERPROFILE` as an example using `ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentalVariables` to some arbitrary directory, but it didn't work. It set the environmental variable `USERPROFILE` to the correct value, but calling `SHGetFolderPath` or `Environment.GetFolder` still returns the previous value.

Any ideas on how I can get the whole way there?

Here is the test app I wrote for this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Any(x => x.Contains("x")))
        {
            // Read vars
            Console.WriteLine("a=" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("a"));// a=tacos
            Console.WriteLine("USERPROFILE=" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE")); //USERPROFILE=F:\UP
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)); // C:\Users\Username
            Console.WriteLine();
            var allvars = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
            foreach (var key in allvars.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", key, allvars[key]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done Second Process");
        }
        else
        {
            // Start new process
            var proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            proc.Arguments = "x";
            proc.EnvironmentVariables["a"] = "tacos";
            proc.EnvironmentVariables["USERPROFILE"] = @"F:\UP";
            proc.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            proc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.RedirectStandardError = true;
            var p = Process.Start(proc);
            do
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                Console.Out.Write(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            }
            while (!p.HasExited);
            //catch any leftovers in redirected stdout
            Console.Out.Write(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            Console.WriteLine("Any Key");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be of some help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37549/CLR-Injection-Runtime-Method-Replacer

Comment: I can see how that'd work for .net executables, but everything else would still fail, so it's not quite what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows is not, as far as I know, designed for chroot-style behavior. The closest you get is filesystem virtualization, but that a) has nothing to do with `SHGetFolderPath` and b) is implemented without regard for generality. So I don't think what you're looking for is really possible.